# Advantages of partitioning RAID HDs?

Tags: raid, software-raid, raid5

I have a bunch of identical, brand new HDs (4*3T, if it matters) I need to use for a single RAID5 array (Linux mdmadm).

It is still undecided if I'll use the entire combined content for a single FileSystem (ext4?) or I'll partition in several virtual drives using LVM.

RAID5 will span the full content of the disks and I don't need boot sector (booting is from another device).

In this condition is there any advantages (or disadvantages) to "traditionally partitioning" the drive with a single partition vs using the whole, unpartitioned, device as base for `mdmadm assemble`?

Saying the same thing in a different way: Is there any advantage in doing

```
mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=5 --raid-devices=3 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1 --spare-devices=1 /dev/sde1
```

versus

```
mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=5 --raid-devices=3 /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd --spare-devices=1 /dev/sde
```

beside trivial loss of a few sectors in the former (which is a negligible "disadvantage")?

Comment: Using RAID5 with such big disks is very fisky. When one disk fails, and you replace it, resilvering the RAID array takes quite a long time, and if another disks fails during that time, you have lost all your data.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen: regular nightly backup on remote NSS **is** in place. What would be the advice? AFAIK partitioning the drives in smaller chunks will not buy me time. Adding more smaller drives is not an option because of number of available SATA ports (I have 6) and cost (smaller disks cost MORE). I am exploring using zfs, but that's another story...

Comment: If you can afford the downtime of restoring from backup when array breaks, then RAID5 is fine. RAID6 should be the minimum, that is, two redundancy disks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partitioning a disk for MD RAID duties has some advatanges:

- MBR/GPT partition table serves as a protective layer if/when the disks are installed on a non-linux machine (a partition table is a strong indication the disk was in using in other systems and it may contain valuable data);
- using a *slightly smaller* partition (versus the entire disk size) ensure that you can replace one failed disk with another 3 TB model even if the latter misses some sectors (ie: it is slightly smaller than the original disk);
- you can dedicate some partitions to a different RAID layout based on the expected data (for example, using RAID0 for swap and scratch data).

For simplicitly sake, if not booting off the RAID array and not needing a swap partition on it, I would probably not use partition for the MD array. This is especially true when using RAID inside a virtual machines, where the underlying disk can be resized by the hypervisor (requiring you to resize the partition table *before* growing the array).

On the other hands, for a bare metal installation, using a partition table for a RAID array only commands an extremely small overhead/annoyance, so if any of the above points is significant for you, go ahead with partitioning.